# C# Unity don't find isServer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a multiplayer game and I need isServer but VisualStudios don't find it.
I used UnityEngine.Networking and isLocalPlayer is working.

Comment: Check out the libraries you've added on top of the file.

Comment: Is your class a [`NetworkBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.html)?